# Windows echo command can't echo a user-set variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, windows-console

What did I do to screw up my CMD shell?  Windows XP Pro, open a cmd window and do:

```
C:\>set tt = name

C:\>set tt
tt = name

C:\>echo %tt%
%tt%

C:\>echo %time%
14:13:28.67
```

The echo command doesn't work for some reason.  I can echo the built-in variables just fine.  Tried it on another computer and that works as expected

Comment: Minor nitpick: `%time%` isn't an environment variable but rather a pseudo-variable that is dynamically evaluated.

Comment: Note that the reason `set tt` works to display the value of the variable is that `set var` displays all variables **beginning with** `var`. You may notice the space between `tt` and `=` in the system output. Also, the value of the variable includes the initial space. For example `echo last%tt %` would output `last name`, which could be what is desired.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `set` command does not take spaces.  The proper syntax would be:

```
set tt=name
```

What you have done in your example is set an environment variable `tt<space>`.  With that in mind, you can try this:

```
echo %tt %
```

and see your output.

Answer (score 10):

The most upvoted answer here, accepted far ago, claims that:

> "The `set` command does not take spaces."

But that is not correct: The `%tt %` variable actually works: It can be set and referenced. (Despite it *is* confusing.)

### Problem reproduced:

Indeed, on my Win7:

```
C:\>set os
OS=Windows_NT

C:\>set tt = name
C:\>set tt2= name
C:\>set tt3=name
C:\>set tt
tt = name
tt2= name
tt3=name
```

I tried and got:

```
C:\>echo "%os%"
"Windows_NT"

C:\>echo "%tt3%"
"name"
C:\>echo "%tt2%"
" name"
C:\>echo "%tt%"
"%tt%"
```

### Resolved cases:

The intuitively expected variable `%tt%` is not set. **But `%tt %` is set instead:**

```
C:\>echo "%tt %"
" name"
```

Even more, with a space at the end of the value, `set     tt4 = name` :

```
C:\>echo "%tt4 %"
" name "
```

### Conclusions:

The `set` command does not `trim()`:

- The space before "=" is included to the `var_name` .
- The space after "=" is included to the  `var_value`.
- The space at the end of the `var_value`  is included to it.

On the other hand:

- The space at the beginning of the `var_name` is not included to it, which is rather normal for command line arguments in general.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer with more information.

Comment: This is simply a (wordy) duplicate of the accepted answer (from over seven years ago).

Comment: I do not agree, that the question was answered, not fully: There is said that %tt % is wrong... But it works, it *can* be used. So now it is shown here, for every one.

Comment: The accepted answer showed an alternative, working syntax; however, the initial statement, "The `set` command does not take spaces" is incorrect. This answer (despite its wordiness) explains the nuances of how the `set` command actually works regarding spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried setting the variable with no space between the equals? (set tt=name)

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer does not work in my Windows 11 system!

```
set JAVA_HOME "C:\example"
```

was successful, and to print the result in the command line I used:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: This is definitively false, it looks more like **bash** (but even there it's wrong). In batch the syntax of the `SET`  command is `set var=content` or even better `set "var=content"`

Comment: This is PowerShell (completely different from `cmd`, as requested in the question). `set` is an alias for the PS-command `Set-Variable`